# Copy a range from one worksheet to another using cells property

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I am trying to copy a range from one worksheet to another.  I have multiple ranges that I would like to copy and paste at various points in the new worksheet though (for example, I want to paste the first range to D3, then the next range to E12, and so on), so I am using the cells property to describe the range.  However, for some reason, when I describe the range that I want to paste at in the new worksheet using the cells format rather than just putting in a string, it does not work.

This line of code does work:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(10, 3)).Copy _
  Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D3")
```

but this one does not:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(10, 3)).Copy _
  Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(3,4))
```

When I run the latter line of code, I get a "Run-time error 1004: application-defined or object defined error".  Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are specifying the parent of Range but not of Cells. In short, you are trying to define a range of cells on Sheet1 that contain the cells on Sheet2 and/or vise-versa.

```
dim ws2 as worksheet
set ws2 = sheets("Sheet2")

with sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(10, 3)).Copy _
      Destination:=ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(3,4))
end with
```

The prefixing period (aka `.` or *full stop*) means that the parent of `.Range` and `.Cells` is defined with the [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). To shorten the code necessary to properly define the range on Sheet2, I assigned a worksheet type variable and used it to show the parent of both the range and the cells.

FWIW, `ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(3,4))` is redundant. `ws2.Cells(3,4)` is sufficient.

Comment: Another in a long line of good reasons to _never_ use implicit references.

Comment: ++ nicely explained :) You are on fire today :)